# how to send HTTP request with 2 IP addresses of the server?

Tags: python, server, python-requests

I have a virtual server that has 2 IP addresses. I wrote a python script that sends HTTP request (by using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library). the script is the following:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
}

url = 'https://www.google.com'

request_no_proxy = requests.get(
    url,
    headers=headers,
)
```

by default, it sends the request with primary IP of the server. how can I send request by second IP of the server?

Comment: Define "primary IP" and "second IP". Primary IP may be your public IP and second IP may be your private IP. Am I correct?

Comment: @ElisByberi No, both of them are public. the first was matched with ns1.mysite.com and the second with ns2.mysite.com.

Comment: These may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148308/2430448 + https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221783/2430448