# Making Python Requests through specific network interface

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, raspberry-pi

I have multiple network interfaces on my Raspberry Pi, all of them have the same IP addresses (192.168.3.1), but named as following: eth1, eth2, etc.

Is there a way to make a request through a specific network interface, even though the IP address is the same? For example, run through `eth2`.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```py
class Modem(object):
  BASE_URL = 'http://{host}'
  TOKEN_URL = '/api/webserver/SesTokInfo'
  session = None

  def __init__(self,host='192.168.3.1'):
    self.host = host
    self.base_url = self.BASE_URL.format(host=host)
    self.session = requests.Session()

  def switch_modem(self, state='02'):
    try:
      # Get session and verification tokens from the modem
      r = self.session.get(self.base_url + self.TOKEN_URL, timeout=10)
      _dict = xmltodict.parse(r.text).get('response', None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fresh enough requests and urllib you can pass extra socket options. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35278688/745924

You can use that to set [SO_BINDTODEVICE](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket#:%7E:text=SO_BINDTODEVICE) on a socket before making requests. For example:

```
import requests
import socket

class HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.socket_options = kwargs.pop("socket_options", None)
        super(HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.socket_options is not None:
            kwargs["socket_options"] = self.socket_options
        super(HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)

interface = 'veth0'
adapter = HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions(socket_options=[(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface.encode('utf-8'))])
session = requests.session()
session.mount("http://", adapter)
session.mount("https://", adapter)
session.get('http://192.168.3.1')
```

You are breaking link and ip layer separation by doing this. It does require root and might not work anyway for many other reasons.